# Whether Oracle Data Guard re-transmits logs from their starting after network interruptions?

Tags: oracle, dataguard

Whether Oracle re-transmits logs from starting after any network interruptions?

If yes, Please advise on how to configure (or) instruct Oracle Data Guard to resume a failed log transfer from where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced network interruptions in my running data guard setup and there were situations were log shipping from primary to standby was stopped.

In those situations I restarted the standby data guard and it started to transfer the log again.

On primary DB, stop the log shipping:

```
alter system set log_archive_dest_state_2=defer;
```

On standby side, restart the DB.

Once the restart is completed, start the log shipping from primary side:

```
alter system set log_archive_dest_state_2=ENABLE;
```

Now, to start real time apply, you need to include the using current logfile phrase in your recover command from standby DB:

```
SQL> alter database recover managed standby database using current logfile disconnect from session;
```